# Java Multilateration Implementation based on Wikipedia Equations

Tags: java, algorithm, position, implementation, indoor-positioning-system

I am trying to write a multilateration algorithm in java to test it out for a project I am working on but am having some issues. I followed the algorithm on the wikipedia page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilateration#Solution_with_limited_computational_resources) (eqn 7) but when I try it out I get the wrong answer.

Here is the data I am trying it with

```
double[] truth = new double[] {1, 4, 8};
double[][] sensorLocations = new double[][] {
        {0, 0, 0},
        {1, 15, 8},
        {13, 4, 8},
        {1, 4, 20}          
};
double[] timeDelays = new double[] {9, 11, 
            12, 12 };
```

Note for the time delays I am assuming v = 1 for simplicity sake in coming up with the answer. Since I did this I made up some time delays and positioned the sensors knowing that the delay (since v = 1) is the same as the distance (sqrt(deltax^2 + deltay^2 + deltaz^2))

However, when I run it through my algorithm I get x = 0.1064, y = 4.2419, z = 8.5968. I know this can't be a solution because the distance from the points don't match up with the times.

Here is my algorithm in java (I assumed that the closest/smallest time was the first point again for simplicity in the first cut of the algorithm)

```
public double[] CalculatePosition(double[][] sensors, double[] timeDelays)
{
    double[] position = new double[3];
    
    //calculate the planes...
    double v = 1;
    double vt1 = v*timeDelays[0];
    
    double[] a = new double[timeDelays.length - 1];
    double[] b = new double[timeDelays.length - 1];
    double[] c = new double[timeDelays.length - 1];
    double[] d = new double[timeDelays.length - 1];
    for(int m = 1; m < timeDelays.length; m++)
    {
        double vtm = v*timeDelays[m];
        a[m-1] = 2*sensors[m][0]/vtm - 2*sensors[0][0]/vt1;
        b[m-1] = 2*sensors[m][1]/vtm - 2*sensors[0][1]/vt1;
        c[m-1] = 2*sensors[m][2]/vtm - 2*sensors[0][2]/vt1;
        d[m-1] = vtm - vt1 - 
                (sensors[m][0] * sensors[m][0] + sensors[m][1] * sensors[m][1] + 
                        sensors[m][2] * sensors[m][2])/vtm + 
                (sensors[0][0] * sensors[0][0] + sensors[0][1] * sensors[0][1] + 
                        sensors[0][2] * sensors[0][2])/vt1; 
        //negate d to make it in the right form for Gaussian elimination
        //i.e. from Ax + By + cZ + D = 0 to Ax + By + cZ = D
        d[m-1] = -d[m-1];
    }
    
    //Calculate where they intersect best
    //Gaussian elimination for now...
    //make the 2 and 3 a 0
    double mult2 = -a[1] / a[0];
    a[1] += mult2 * a[0];
    b[1] += mult2 * b[0];
    c[1] += mult2 * c[0];
    d[1] += mult2 * d[0];
    
    double mult3 = -a[2] / a[0];
    a[2] += mult3 * a[0];
    b[2] += mult3 * b[0];
    c[2] += mult3 * c[0];
    d[2] += mult3 * d[0];
    
    mult3 = -b[2] / b[1];
    a[2] += mult3 * a[1];
    b[2] += mult3 * b[1];
    c[2] += mult3 * c[1];
    d[2] += mult3 * d[1];
    
    //now use substitution to get the answer!
    position[2] = d[2] / c[2];
    position[1] = (d[1] - position[2] * c[1]) / b[1];
    position[0] = (d[0] - position[1] * b[0] - position[2] * c[0]) / b[0];
    
    
    return position;
}
```

Can anyone help me find the issue with the algorithm implementation, the data I am using to test it, or any assumptions I made?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Any specific reason for following:

```
double[] a = new double[timeDelays.length - 1];
double[] b = new double[timeDelays.length - 1];
double[] c = new double[timeDelays.length - 1];
double[] d = new double[timeDelays.length - 1];
```

because below you are accessing third element and this would overflow when length of `timeDelays` is 3.